# Imaginary numbers in AC circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, complex-numbers, linear-systems

I've heard/read multiple times that "the use of imaginary numbers in ac circuits simplyfy calculations". My questions is: **how is the calculations simplified?** (exaple calculations?) And **what does the different parts of the imaginary voltage/current (and impedence) mean?**

(I use $j$ as the imaginary unit below (because it is custom in electronics), even though I usually prefer $i$. That is why I by a mistake typed $i$ when labeling the axis in the image)

Here is what I think so far:

---

### How calculations are simplified

A capacitor obeys the equation: $I(t)=C\frac{dV}{dt}$. Using $C\approx dQ/dV$, we get $I(t)\approx \frac{dQ}{dV}\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ (chain rule). Which means this equation is just another way to say that *current is charge per time unit*. If we use $V(t)=V_0e^{j\omega t}$ as a solution for the voltage, we get: $C\frac{dV}{dt}=j\omega C V_0e^{j\omega t}$. Combining this with the fact that $Z=\frac{V}{I}$, we get $Z=1/(j\omega C)$. By a similar process we get $Z=j\omega L$ for an inductor.

We know that $1/j=-j$, which means $Z=-j\frac{1}{\omega C}$. A property of  imaginary numbers is that multiplication is also a *rotation*. If we express the number using polar cordinates $(|z|,\varphi)$, we can express multiplication like this: $(|z|_1,\varphi_1)\cdot (|z|_2,\varphi_2)=(|z|_1\cdot|z|_2, \varphi_1+\varphi_2)$. This means that *a capacitor introduces a phase shift of $270^{\circ}$ (or $-90^{\circ}$)* (in the current?) and *an inductor introduces a phase shift of $90^{\circ}$* (in the voltage?). I know there is a $90^{\circ}$ *difference* between the current and voltage, but which leads and which lags behind?

Also, since $\omega=2\pi f >1\text{Hz}$ (for $f>1/(2\pi)\text{Hz}$, which I guess is most AC frequencies) and assuming $L\geq 1\text{H}=1\Omega/\text{Hz},C\geq 1F=1\Omega^{-1}\text{Hz}^{-1}$, then in addition to a phase shift the current/ voltage amplitude is changed.
For a capacitor, the amplitude is reduced and for an inducrtor the amplitude is increased. (**Why?**)

**Edit:** If the same current $I$ is sent through a capacitor and an inductor, the voltage in the inductor *is greater than in the capacitor*: $V_L=Z\cdot I \Rightarrow V_L=j\omega L \cdot I >j\cdot I$ and $V_C=Z\cdot I=-j \cdot 1/(\omega C) \cdot I<-j\cdot I$. Overall we have $|V_L|>|V_C|$ (in most cases?).

[image]

Is there other calculations that is simplified by the use of imaginary numbers or is it just the calculations involving a capacitor and/or an inductor? Are the calculations simplified because you can get the phase shift *and* amplitude change by doing a simple multiplication?

### What the imaginary parts mean

I think I read somewhere that the imaginary part of the impendance (the *reactance* $X$), is the storage of energy inside the device, while the *resistance* ($R$) is the dissipation of energy (in form of heat or light or other forms). $Z=R+jX$. Something I wonder is *how is the energy stored?* and in what form of energy? Some kind of potential energy?

As for the voltage (and similarly current) it can be expressed as $V(t)=V_0e^{j(\omega t+\varphi)}=V_0 \sin (\omega t + \varphi)+jV_0\cos (\omega t + \varphi)$. Where $\varphi$ is the phase shift. Then for an imaginary number $V_1=a+bj$, $a$ is the value of the voltage. *But what is $b$?*

I think the angle $\arg(a+bj)=\omega t + \varphi$. This, however, means that it is impossible to tell the frequency from just one number alone. This makes intuitive sense to me: if you only measure the voltage at, say $t=1\text{s}$, then you can not determine the frequency of the signal.

If $a$ is the value of the voltage, then what is $|a+bj|$ (the modulus of the imaginary voltage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, so I'll repeat some of what you said, with occasional edits.

> how is the calculations simplified?

The ODE we want to solve ($L\ddot{Q}+R\dot{Q}+C^{-1}Q=V$ with $L,\,R,\,C^{-1},\,V$ real-valued) is linear, and the most general real solution is the real part of the most general complex solution (possibly with $V$ also changed to a complex-valued function whose real-part is the physical $V$), and the easiest way to obtain the former is to obtain the latter first. If you want an example, consider the case $V=V_0\cos\omega t$, which under this strategy is changed to $V=V_0e^{j\omega t}$.

> what does the different parts of the imaginary voltage/current (and impedance) mean?

The case $L=C^{-1}=0$ reduces the problem to $R\dot{Q}=V$ so the complex solution is $Q=Q_0+\frac{V_0}{j\omega R}(e^{j\omega t}-1)$ or, in terms of current, $I=\frac{V_0}{R}e^{j\omega t}$. More generally, we find solutions of $L\ddot{I}+R\dot{I}+C^{-1}I=\dot{V}$ viz. $V=V_0e^{j\omega t},\,I=\frac{V_0}{Z}e^{j\omega t}$ for complex $Z=R+jX,\,X:=\omega L-\frac{1}{\omega C}$. We call $X$ the [reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance). If $\omega$ is tuned to $1/\sqrt{LC}$, $Z=R$ minimizes $|Z|$, i.e. maximizing $|I|$.

> there is a $\pi/2$ difference between the current and voltage, but which leads and which lags behind?

If you turn on $V$ at a finite time, $V=V_0\cos\omega t$ is physically unrealistic at first, and in practice $Q,\,I$ will lag because they're caused by $V$. In the long term, though, you won't be able to notice. (Even more fundamentally, the power supplied causes the voltage, which causes the current.)

> $\omega=2\pi f >1$

You can't compare $\omega$ to $1$; they have different dimensions.

> The current/ voltage amplitude is changed.

Again, they can't be compare because their dimensions differ. As I've mentioned, though, $\omega=1/\sqrt{LC}$ maximizes the amplitude of $I$ at a fixed amplitude for $V$.

> For a capacitor, the amplitude is reduced and for an inductor the amplitude is increased.

Wrong: any non-zero value for $X$, regardless of sign, reduces the current's amplitude. If you want to maximize current, set $\omega^2LC=1$. This is an example of [*impedance matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching), although in practice such matching may have a different goal, so may achieve a different value of $\omega^2LC$. (And in series and parallel currents, the analysis is further complicated.)

> how is the energy stored? and in what form of energy? Some kind of potential energy?

As *Wikipedia* mentions when discussing reactance,

> Reactance is similar to resistance in this respect, but differs in that reactance does not lead to dissipation of electrical energy as heat. Instead, energy is momentarily stored in the reactance, and a quarter-cycle later returned to the circuit, whereas a resistance continuously loses energy.

In particular, reactance stores energy in the electromagnetic field. All these facts about circuits are emergent consequences of more general facts about this field, which also benefit from complex numbers in much the same way.

> $V_1=a+bj$, $a$ is the value of the voltage. *But what is $b$?*

The complex voltage introduced in the above techniques has a physically meaningful amplitude; its phase *relative to the current* is similarly meaningful, but its overall phase is not, since we can give the same overall phase shift to all complex variables. Therefore, the real & imaginary parts don't "mean" anything either.

Comment: When I wrote $\omega>1$ I meant in magnitude/ numerical value. Is $L\propto \omega$ such that $\omega L<1$ (in numerical value? Also, isn't the real part of the voltage the strenght of the signal at time $t$?

Comment: @Vebjorn Again, **you can't compare quantities of different dimension**. Is your height "greater than $1$"? ($1$ what?) You can, however, talk about how big or small $\omega^2LC$ is, as that's just a number. As for the real part of voltage, that constrains which "complex voltages" are accurate descriptions, but the imaginary part is just a convention. It's a consequence of the chosen phase; it's equivalent to specifying which moment you label as $t=0$.

Comment: A $L=20 \text{H}=20\text{Wb/A}=20\Omega\text{/Hz}$ inductor with current with frequency $f=50\text{Hz}$: $V=ZI \Rightarrow V=j\omega L \cdot I \Rightarrow V\approx j 6 280\Omega \cdot I $. So, the value of the voltage is about 6 000 times grater than the current?

Comment: @Vebjorn Only in SI units. If you worked with kiloohms, it'd only be about $6$ times greater. Again, it's like asking whether your height is "more" or "less" than $1$. Sure, it's (probably) more than $1$ in metres, but certainly not in light years. I strongly advise you not to think of quantities as big or small compared to those of a different dimension.